# NoSuchElementException 2-d array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I keep getting NoSuchElementException but I'm not sure why. I know the error is for the scanner but don't know the reason this error is happening. I included the input file.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Numbrosia {
    static int [][] board = new int [5][5];
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner scan = null;
        try{
            scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return; 
        }
        for(int row = 0; row<board.length; row++){
            for(int col= 0; col<board.length;col++){
                board[row][col] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
    while(true){
                    showBoard();
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("Input number from 1 to 5: ");
                    int  i = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Input move command: ");
                    String moveName = scan.next();
                    //If/ else statements to dictate which method to call
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
    at excercises.Numbrosia.main(Numbrosia.java:25)
```

Input file:

```
1 -2  1  0  0
-1  0  4  2  0
 0 -4  1 -1  0
 0  1 -1 -1 -2
 0 -3  1 -1  0
```

Comment: Can you post some more code?

Comment: Is the exception thrown on the first iteration of the loop?

Comment: I just posted more code

Comment: in which line it gives you this exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your scanner is not being told to read user input after it finishes reading from the file, It is still trying to read from the file after it asks the user for a number. You need to create a new Scanner to read from the keyboard.
Use the following code for the while loop:

```
scan.close();
Scanner kbScan = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true){
    showBoard();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Input number from 1 to 5: ");
    //This will read from the keyboard
    int i = kbScan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input move command: ");
    String moveName = scan.next();
```

Anywhere else in the method that you need to read from the keyboard, use `kbScan` instead of `scan`.